# failed to disable the ContextMenu for QFileDialog

Tags: qt

I am using a `QFileDialog` in my Qt program through which the user should not be allowed to modify or delete the selected files. I therefore do not need the right click menu at all in the pop-up file dialog.

I tried two methods to disable it as shown below but failed, the right click menu does not disappear, can anybody help me to disable/prevent/set_invisible the right click menu?

```
//#define NOMENUCLASS 1
#ifdef NOMENUCLASS
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QNoMenuFileDialog : public QFileDialog
{
public:
    QNoMenuFileDialog();
    ~QNoMenuFileDialog();
protected:
    void ShowContextMenu(const QPoint& pos);
};
void QNoMenuFileDialog::ShowContextMenu(const QPoint& pos) {}
QNoMenuFileDialog::QNoMenuFileDialog(){}
QNoMenuFileDialog::~QNoMenuFileDialog(){}
#endif
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QStringList mimeTypeFilters;
    mimeTypeFilters << "image/jpeg" /*will show "JPEG image (*.jpeg *.jpg *.jpe)*/ 
                << "image/png"  /*will show "PNG image (*.png)"*/ 
                << "application/octet-stream"; /*will show "All files (*)"*/ 
#ifdef NOMENUCLASS
    /*1. try to disable the right click menu using a invalid function ShowContextMenu --failed */
    QNoMenuFileDialog dialog;
    dialog.setMimeTypeFilters(mimeTypeFilters);
    dialog.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
#else
    /*2. try to disable the right click menu using setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::PreventContextMenu) --failed */
    QFileDialog dialog;
    dialog.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::PreventContextMenu);
#endif
    if(dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
            QString path = dialog.selectedFiles()[0];
            QMessageBox::information(NULL, tr("Path"), tr("You selected ") + path);
    } else {
            QMessageBox::information(NULL, tr("Path"), tr("You didn't select any files."));
    }
}
```

Comment: I started to put your sample code into a minimal, complete example. First thing I've noticed: The file dialog looks like the native file dialog (if it isn't the native). There are a lot of different popup menus depending on where I do the right click. I'm afraid they cannot be supressed (because originating from Windows/Explorer behavior). (I forgot to mention that I'm speaking about / testing on Windows 10.)

Comment: Yes, I used the below code to set native, in the two case, the menu are different with each other, but both cannot be disabled. So are there any method to Block the right click event/signal to system IN THE FILEDIALOG?                                                                                

filedialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog, true);
filedialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog, false);

Comment: What about creating your own file dialog?

Comment: Have you tried to set the option `QFileDialog::ReadOnly`?

Comment: Yes， I tried QFileDialog::ReadOnly to avoid the problem.

    `QString FilePath;
    QFileDialog dialog(NULL,
                       tr("UpdateDialog"),
                       UpgradeDirPath,
                       tr("UpdateImage(*.img)"));
    dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::ReadOnly);
    if(dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
  FilePath = dialog.selectedFiles()[0];
  ...
 ｝
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried QFileDialog::ReadOnly to avoid the problem. `dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::ReadOnly);`